Pytesseract doesnt recognize plate correctly
I am using pytesseract to try to recognize car plates but it does not return the correct result.
This is my code
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped_License_Plate, lang='eng', config='--psm 9')

I have tried using many different psm but the result is never correct.
My images

Plate QAN-5512
Pyressecat reading: DAN S512

Plate RWC2I30
Pytesseract reading: 'RWC213G

Plate RWC2I30
Pytesseract reading: FRWOZLSU
Is there a way to fix it?

Use a different OCR tool. Recommend Paddle OCR if inputs will be materially slanted.

Using Paddle OCR worked great
Thanks @JJFord3
